# Spring Batch Item Reader Reading Same Items Multiple Times

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, spring-batch

I am using a `JpaPagingItemReader` and I noticed that it is reading the same rows more than once. In the documentation it does say that "Caller might get the same item twice from successive calls (or otherwise), if the first call was in a transaction that rolled back." but when I checked the roll back count it was 0. I added all listeners with logs in each method and the reading, processing and writing all complete successfully (`onError()` is never called). What could be causing the loading of the same item more than once?

UPDATE:
The JPAPagingItemReader is configured as follows

```
<bean id="reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader" scope="step" p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" >
        <property name="queryString" value="SELECT item FROM Item item WHERE item.batchId = #{jobParameters[batchId]}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Doesn't this part #{jobParameters[batchId] always return same value? I think that this might be your problem... Meaning your query string is not updated between reader runs.

Comment: batchId identifies the items that need to be processed as is unique for every new job. The problem is that for the one job with one step the same item is read multiple times

Comment: I tried setting the commit count to 1 but the issue still persists

Comment: Are there ways to enforce spring batch to only process an item once, especially for those that have been processed successfully?

Comment: I'm having the similar problem with HibernatePagingItemReader. I know its been 7 years since the question but have you found a solution? @SamanthaCatania
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74558864/spring-batch-hibernatepagingitemreader-reads-the-same-data-more-than-once

Comment: @Omeerfk I ended up moving away from spring batch :(